# Set condition before running Vlookup VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I created a Vlookup but first want a condition to be met to determine what Vlookup to use.

Such as

If cell = 1 then
run Vlookup #1

If cell = 2 then
run Vlookup #2

There are only 4 possible variables that the cell could equal. This would have to be on a loop, because the entries in the worksheet are multiple. It would first see what the specific cell equaled, then determine what Vlookup to use.

Any insight?

Comment: You can use `CHOOSE()` for this.  Check out the Help for that function. Or use nested `IF()`'s.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need a loop because this might be handled within the VLOOKUP, though I am assuming the conditional cell (one of four values) is not the trigger cell for the VLOOKUP:

[image: SO21807849 example]

Here A1 is the condition, C1 the trigger value and D1 contains the formula for the lookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$H$1:$L$3,A1+1,0)
```

and hence also the result `k` in the example.

A2 merely determines how many columns across to step when looking for the appropriate value in the lookup table (here in the box).

We know from ColumnH that `20` is in the second row of the table and `A1+1` says take the value A1 (ie four) columns further to the right.

Change the blue to `2` and the yellow to `30`, for example, and the result is `f`.

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is what I am looking for. I'll try to explain it a little better using your example. Column A is the variable, and say it can either equal 4 or 5. 4 relates to the data in Columns H:L. 5 relates to a different table, measurements and data a little different. So what I'm trying to do is if Cell A = 4 then =VLOOKUP(C1,$H$1:$L$3,2,0), or if Cell A = 5 =VLOOKUP(C1,$J$1:$E$3,4,0). C1 is the trigger value, but Column A determines what Vlookup to run. I hope that makes it a little clearer. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If values are for sure integers 1 to N, just like @Tim pointed out you can use CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(A1;Vlookup1;Vlookup2;...;VlookupN)
```

If A1=1 Vlookup1 will be executed, A1=2 Vlookup2....A1=N... VlookupN

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you both CRondao and Tim! I haven't tried it yet, but this would keep on running correct? For example A1 = 1, then A2 = 4. The value in column A is dependent on user input.

Comment: Is there a way to put that in the VBA? I want to avoid putting the formulas in the cells. The number of entries are not consistent, and once the bugs are out others will be using it. I would like it simplified for other users. What you are saying makes sense to me, but I want it so you can click a button and its done

Comment: Worksheets("Report_Draft").Cells(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Report_Draft").Cells(i, 4), [pt_master], 2, False)    Would I do something similar for the CHOOSE function? @CRondao

Comment: Using vba you dont need choose just say: If Range("A1") =1 then ... else if Range("A1")=2 then....